# Slick carousel - If fade in parent element, then first image doesn't show

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using Ken Wheeler's slick carousel.

The parent element of my slideshow is faded out (fadeOut()).

When I click something, I want the parent element and the slideshow to fade in.

All works well except on mobile phones, at least on Android. On my Android phone, the first image doesn't load.

If I don't fade the parent element out, but just set the opacity to 0, then the first image of the slideshow shows up, *but* I have a big space on my homepage where that invisible element is.

Anyone know how to handle this please?

jQuery:

```
$('.bridge_story_mobile').fadeOut(); // they need to be display:block 

$('.bridge_holder').on('tap', function() {
    var mobile_toshow = $(this).attr('id');
    mobile_toshow = mobile_toshow.replace('holder_', '');
    mobile_toshow = mobile_toshow + "_mobile";

    $('#' + mobile_toshow).detach().insertAfter('.bridges_wrapper');

    $('.bridges_wrapper').fadeOut(1200, function() {
        $('.bridge_story_mobile').css('display', 'none');
        $('#' + mobile_toshow).css({"opacity":"0", 'display':'block'});
        $('#' + mobile_toshow).animate({"opacity":"1", 'z-index':'2'},2000);
        $('.mobile_close').animate({"opacity":"1", 'z-index':'99'},2000);
        var $slider = $('.slider')
            .on('init', function(slick) {
                console.log('fired!');
                $('.slider').fadeIn(3000);
            })
            .slick({
                fade: true,
                focusOnSelect: true,
                lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
                speed: 1000
            });
        $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#mobile").offset().top -0
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add a MCVE?

Comment: @ShikatsuKagaminara: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bridges/ohio/

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that because you initialize the plugin while html is hidden, it gives all divs a size of 0px.

[image]

To fix, you could run a refresh on each of your slideshows once they are visible:

```
$('#ss_mobile_mainstory')[0].slick.refresh();
```

Comment: That may be it -- let me check. Right now I'm just setting my parent div to height:0 to hide it.

Comment: There's many ways to solve but I'm fairly certain that this is the actual cause of the problem in your question.